# How to display input wait queue details of job of all lpars with JCL

Tags: mainframe, jcl, sdsf

I'm trying to get the output of waiting jobs in all plexes by running a JCL, but I don't seem to get the desired results. My code used:

```
//SDSF  EXEC PGM=SDSF                            
//SYSOUT DD SYSOUT=*                             
//ISFOUT DD DSN=<MY TEST FILE>,  
//          DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),                
//          DCB=(RECFM=FBA,LRECL=133,BLKSIZE=0), 
//          SPACE=(CYL,(1,1)),UNIT=SYSDA         
//ISFIN  DD *                                    
  /$DQ,Q=XEQ                                     
  ULOG                                           
/*                                               
//*
```

What I get in my output file is just "RO *ALL,$DQ,Q=XEQ*" the results of that command don't seem to appear. But if I execute the same command in sdsf panel, I get all the details. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to my mind that might help.

#1. I would rather use **PGM=IKJEFT01** here. Done it for years for tons of commands and never failed.
Something in the flavour of:

```
//STEP01 EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01
//SYSTOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSTIN DD *
CONSOLE NAME(XXXXX)
$jes_command_here
END
/*
```

#2. When you submit jobs that invoke commands via console it usually wants to take hold of the one you have in the SDSF profile set as default. Therefore you might run into an error when you have your ulog open in sdsf(for this lpar or any other in the plex) on a split when you submit the job. So make sure to have the console/ulog not used when running jobs like these.

Jarek.